# How do I return a value from a function triggered by Timer

Tags: swift

I have created a timer to trigger the function `timerFire`, every 5 seconds accepting the Double `howHungry` from another swift file.

The timer takes the value of `howHungry` and reduces it by 1 every time the timer fires and returns the new value.

Once the new value of `howHungry` is returned how can i retrieve the new value of `howHungry` to **file1.swift**?

As the original value is not being reduced the same value is sent each time

**Console is currently showing:**

```
Hunger value is 14.0
Hunger value is 14.0
Hunger value is 14.0
```

**file1.swift**

```
    let hungerTimer = myTimer()

    hungerTimer.startTimer(timerInitialValue: howHungry)
```

**file2.swift**

```
    func startTimer(timerInitialValue:Double){
    
        if timer == nil{ //Create a new timer for hunger if one doesn't exist
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFire(sender:)), userInfo: timerInitialValue/*how hungry*/, repeats: true)
            print("New Timer Started")

        }else{ //If a timer does exist, end it and start a new one.

            timer!.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            print("Old Timer Stopped")
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFire(sender:)), userInfo: timerInitialValue, repeats: true)
            print ("Now New Timer Started")
            print(timer)
        }
}

   @objc func timerFire(sender: Timer) -> Double{
        //get hungryDouble value from Timer       
        var hungryDouble = sender.userInfo as! Double
        //Reduce it by 1
        hungryDouble -= 1.0
        print("Hunger value is \(hungryDouble)")
        return(hungryDouble)
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you pass `timerInitialValue` in the `userInfo` parameter which is never be modified. Consider to use an external counter variable. And it's impossible to return something from a target/action selector method.

Comment: Thanks @vadian, I was struggling to send the value of ```howHungry``` to the Timer, I'm using ```userInfo``` to do this.

Comment: The timer calls the selector every 2 seconds, nothing else. It doesn't touch the userInfo parameter. Therefore my suggestion to use an external counter variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a callback inside `file2.swift`

```
var callback:((Double)->())?

@objc func timerFire(sender: Timer){
   //get hungryDouble value from Timer       
   var hungryDouble = sender.userInfo as! Double
   //Reduce it by 1
   hungryDouble -= 1.0
   print("Hunger value is \(hungryDouble)")
   callback?(hungryDouble)
}
```

And inside `file1.swift`

```
let hungerTimer = myTimer()
hungerTimer.startTimer(timerInitialValue: howHungry)
hungerTimer.callback = { [weak self] res in
   print(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I get the following error when declaring the ```callback``` variable
```Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'```

edit: Resolved by adding a colon after the variable name

Comment: @Gaz re copy edit

Comment: It still returns the same value of 14.0.

I've omitted ```[weak self]``` as file1.swift is ```struct```

Comment: don't use `userInfo` and declare a variable inside the struct to keep track of the update